# Why does Travis try to deploy to a non-specified Heroku app?

Tags: git, github, heroku, travis-ci

I have a github repo (`myapp`) using travis to deploy to two heroku apps (`integration-my-app`, `my-app`).

Deployment to `myapp` on heroku has worked previously, but times have changed, the app has been removed and replaced, but travis still keeps trying to deploy to it (and obviously failing).

I have tried to enforce deployment to these new apps by explicitly requesting this in the `.travis.yml` file, but it doesn't seem to be picking this up.

I can push to the correct apps as remotes directly from git cli (e.g. `heroku push integration`).

Here's the yaml

```
language: python
python:
- 3.6.7
env:
  global:
  - TEST_ENV=true
  - INTEGRATION_EMAIL=false
  - AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME_TEST=test-myapp
  - secure: ENCRYPTED_AWS_USERNAME
  - secure: ENCRYPTED_AWS_PASSWORD
  matrix:
  - INTEGRATION_AWS=true
  - INTEGRATION_AWS=false
before_script:
- psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
services:
- postgresql
script:
- python3 manage.py migrate auth
- python3 manage.py migrate myapp
- python3 manage.py migrate
- python3 manage.py test myapp/tests/unit_tests
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: ENCRYPTED_API_KEY_FOR_HEROKU_ACCOUNT
  app: 
    integration: integration-my-app
    staging: my-app
  on:
    branch: master
```

I'd expect this to deploy the master branch to both integration (`integration-my-app`) and staging (`my-app`).  However, instead I get the following error message.

```
checking for app myapp
dpl.2
Preparing deploy
No stash entries found.
API request failed.
Message: Couldn't find that app.
Reference: 
failed to deploy
```